# zsh process file script

Tags: loops, unix, zsh

I'm attempting to have this process a number of files but I don't want it in a look so I don't have to monitor it.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/zsh
X=${1-20}
for (( N=1; N<=X; N++ )); do
        for p in *.xml; do
                    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml"  -d "@${p}" "https://url /postAPI" > "post_${p}"
                        sleep 1
                done
        done
```

When doing ./work.sh 5 this loops forever!

What's causing infinate loop?

**Edit Based on a comment below**

```
/tmp/tmp.KeFYeM9Z % ls -l
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x  1 naes  wheel  218 Nov 20 14:42 work.sh

#!/usr/local/bin/zsh
X=${1-20}
for (( N=1; N<=X; N++ )); do
        for p in /tmp/tmp.u6RnKaJ3/*.xml; do
                    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml"  -d "@${p}" "https://url /postAPI"
                        sleep 1
                done
        done
```

This still continues the infinite loop

This doesn't:

```
 % cat work1.sh
#!/usr/local/bin/zsh
X=${1-20}
for (( N=1; N<=X; N++ )); do
        date
        sleep 1
done



% ./work1.sh 5
Thu Nov 20 15:22:27 PST 2014
Thu Nov 20 15:22:28 PST 2014
Thu Nov 20 15:22:29 PST 2014
Thu Nov 20 15:22:30 PST 2014
Thu Nov 20 15:22:31 PST 2014
```

What in my loop causes the infinite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing to the same directory you are reading from. So while reading the xml files you are writing xml files making it essentially loop forever. Although it's not really an infinite loop, it's a very large one.

Let's say you have 10 files, in that case you'll have this result:

```
N=1: |p| = 100
N=2: |p| = 200
N=3: |p| = 400
N=4: |p| = 800
N=5: |p| = 1600
```

So... it groes quite fast.

This should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/zsh

X=${1-20}
OUTPUT_DIR=/tmp/output/
mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIR

cd /tmp/tmp.u6RnKaJ3
for (( N=1; N<=X; N++ )); do
    echo "Attempt $N"

    for p in *.xml; do
        curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml"  -d "@${p}" "https://url /postAPI" > "${OUTPUT_DIR}post_${p}"
        sleep 1
    done
done
```

Comment: So you're saying just have output save OUTSIDE the directory the script is in? What its it goes to a subdirectory?
/tmp/tmp.u6RnKaJ3 is where I am now. 
`% ./work.sh 1
./work.sh:5: permission denied: /tmppost_9713171.xml
./work.sh:5: permission denied: /tmppost_973805.xml
./work.sh:5: permission denied: /tmppost_9819880.xml
./work.sh:5: permission denied: /tmppost_post_9713171.xml`

Comment: Even when I make a new tmp directory, copy script, cd to that dir, modify it to run in previous directory, it loops without any break.

Comment: @RegisteredUser: try the script I've added